# PHP intval or int typecasting fails on hex string decoded with base64_decode

Tags: php, base64, simplexml

I decoded a hexidecimal value into its original content using base64_decode and exploed the string at its commas into an array. print array shows success, however when I try and use the values for a switch() and it wont work. I try to use intval() to change a number string into an integer and it returns 0. I think it is something to do with the decode but I'm at a loss. I also know that I have some characters at the beginning of the hex value that won't decode

in my code $value is my hex string that comes from parsing a SimpleXMLElement() I have an array of hex payloads that I am looping through with a foreach this is glimpse into one loop:

```
//the hex value im decoding comes from parsing my SimpleXMLElement
//I generate $value = gAExLDUyLjMxOTEsLTExMy45ODc=
//decode it and it gives me a strange character a question mark in a diamond
//diamond thing should decode to "[128][3]" but that doesn't come across.
$result = base64_decode(str_replace(" ","+",$value));

//I trim off the strange character
$result = substr($result,1);

//and get the expected string
//1,52.3191,-113.9870
//so I explode it into an array
$param = explode(',', $result);

// can verify the array with print_r -- all good                        
//but this type cast fails so does intval()
$type = (int)$param[0];

//this is all going on inside a foreach loop
//so the decoded value is different everytime and
//i have different operations to perfrom based
//on the value of $type variable using the switch
//cant get the switch to accept the type variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Decoding the base64 string `gAExLDUyLjMxOTEsLTExMy45ODc=` gives me this sequence of characters:

```
0#    80 hex = 256 dec = 200 oct = character 256 (outside ASCII range)
1#    01 hex = 001 dec = 001 oct = ASCII SOH (start of heading)
2#    31 hex = 049 dec = 061 oct = 1
3#    2C hex = 044 dec = 054 oct = ,
4#    35 hex = 053 dec = 065 oct = 5
5#    32 hex = 050 dec = 062 oct = 2
6#    2E hex = 046 dec = 056 oct = .
7#    33 hex = 051 dec = 063 oct = 3
8#    31 hex = 049 dec = 061 oct = 1
9#    39 hex = 057 dec = 071 oct = 9
10#    31 hex = 049 dec = 061 oct = 1
11#    2C hex = 044 dec = 054 oct = ,
12#    2D hex = 045 dec = 055 oct = -
13#    31 hex = 049 dec = 061 oct = 1
14#    31 hex = 049 dec = 061 oct = 1
15#    33 hex = 051 dec = 063 oct = 3
16#    2E hex = 046 dec = 056 oct = .
17#    39 hex = 057 dec = 071 oct = 9
18#    38 hex = 056 dec = 070 oct = 8
19#    37 hex = 055 dec = 067 oct = 7
```

Note that there are not one but two bytes at the beginning before the 1. You are stripping one of these, but the other is still there when you perform your int cast, so PHP sees the string as not beginning with a digit and gives you `0`.

If you're sure you don't want these characters, you could discard everything other than digits, commas, and dots, before splitting:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $result);
```

Comment: I do want the two bytes at the beginning however I am unable to decode them into readable data. Any ideas why the (int) typecast and intval() fail ?

Comment: @Laurence The string you are trying to cast to int includes (one of) the two bytes at the beginning of the string. As such, it doesn't look like a number, so PHP gives you 0.

Comment: Thanks! that was why my intval() failed. I wish I knew how do I decode those first bytes, but this will keep the ball rolling anyway.

Comment: @Laurence If you need their numeric value, you could use [`ord($result[0])` and `ord($result[1])`](http://php.net/ord).